# Rails - uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Please help, not sure what I'm doing wrong at all. I'm just trying to make a simple search form, and I'm guessing I just have an error in my routes maybe, but I'm not that strong at debugging as I'm fairly new.

The error is -

> uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Article

routes.rb -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Search Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- When submit the form, the view rendered will be the index view of our articles resource -->
  <%= form_tag(articles_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
    <div class="input-append">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "span2", placeholder: "Search Articles" %>
      <!-- In order to have the "search" icon int the button, we need to use plain HTML instead 
           of using a Rails form helper -->
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

articles.rb -

```
def Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  # It returns the articles whose titles contain one or more words that form the query
  def self.search(query)
    # where(:title, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("title like ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
end
```

articles_controller.rb ***THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS**** It highlights "@articles = Article.order("create_at DESC")"

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      **@articles = Article.order("created_at DESC")**
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb -

```
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="article">
    <h1 class="article-title"><%= link_to article.title, article %></h1>
    <p class="article-content"><%= article.content %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

application.html.erb -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Search Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- When submit the form, the view rendered will be the index view of our articles resource -->
  <%= form_tag(articles_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form", id: "search-form") do %>
    <div class="input-append">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "span2", placeholder: "Search Articles" %>
      <!-- In order to have the "search" icon int the button, we need to use plain HTML instead 
           of using a Rails form helper -->
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

In articles.rb you have

```
def Article < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and you should have

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: does it matter the order? the class one goes first right?

Comment: Well, it's not an order thing really.... `def` if for a method definition inside of a class. So what the error is telling you is that it can't find that Article class because you are using `def` and not making a new class. Your model is basically a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to instantiate a new class. Right now you're creating a method that somehow inherits from ActiveRecord.

This (in article.rb):

```
def Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Should be:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: So, delete the "def" basically and replace it with "class"?

Comment: Yes. Right now, your ArticlesController is attempting to communicate with something that's been established as something other than a class. Also, please consider accepting my answer if it's helped you.